# mosquitto bridge publish causing OOM crashes

Tags: mqtt, embedded-linux, iot, mosquitto

We are developing and IoT Edge application where we need to run mosquitto broker in a embedded linux gateway device. The edge broker is bridged to a cloud MQTT broker. Other devices in the edge network publishes to the edge mosquitto broker and mosquitto will publish it to the cloud. The edge gateway is located at a site where network connectivity is very constrained.

An edge device is sending 28KB payload to the mosquitto broker at 1 message per 5 seconds frequency. We could see that the internal queue of the mosquitto goes on increasing ('$SYS/broker/messages/stored'). It increases to fully utilize the gateway memory and then mosquitto crashes.

When we enabled logging in mosquitto and checked, we could see that

1. The time duration between PUBLISH and PUBACKs are huge
2. Because of this huge delay mosquitto is resending the messages multiple times

See logs below for a specific message:

```
1591704254: Sending PUBLISH to local.clientid (d0, q1, r0, m572, 'toCLOUD/Basic', ... (32768 bytes))
1591704275: Sending PUBLISH to local.clientid (d1, q1, r0, m572, 'toCLOUD/Basic', ... (32768 bytes))
1591704296: Sending PUBLISH to local.clientid (d1, q1, r0, m572, 'toCLOUD/Basic', ... (32768 bytes))
1591704317: Sending PUBLISH to local.clientid (d1, q1, r0, m572, 'toCLOUD/Basic', ... (32768 bytes))
1591704338: Sending PUBLISH to local.clientid (d1, q1, r0, m572, 'toCLOUD/Basic', ... (32768 bytes))
1591704359: Sending PUBLISH to local.clientid (d1, q1, r0, m572, 'toCLOUD/Basic', ... (32768 bytes))
1591704380: Sending PUBLISH to local.clientid (d1, q1, r0, m572, 'toCLOUD/Basic', ... (32768 bytes))
1591704401: Sending PUBLISH to local.clientid (d1, q1, r0, m572, 'toCLOUD/Basic', ... (32768 bytes))
1591704422: Sending PUBLISH to local.clientid (d1, q1, r0, m572, 'toCLOUD/Basic', ... (32768 bytes))
1591704526: Received PUBACK from local.clientid (Mid: 572)
1591704597: Received PUBACK from local.clientid (Mid: 572)
1591704680: Received PUBACK from local.clientid (Mid: 572)
1591704750: Received PUBACK from local.clientid (Mid: 572)
1591704838: Received PUBACK from local.clientid (Mid: 572)
1591704901: Received PUBACK from local.clientid (Mid: 572)
1591704975: Received PUBACK from local.clientid (Mid: 572)
1591705039: Received PUBACK from local.clientid (Mid: 572)
1591705120: Received PUBACK from local.clientid (Mid: 572)
```

To recreate this issue I tried using "mosquitto_pub" command in the geteway with same connection information like this:

```
for i in `seq 1 1000`
do
    echo $JSON
done | mosquitto_pub -h broker.cloud.com  -t 'toCLOUD/TEST' -l -q 1
```

But I was not able see the same delay or duplication in the "mosquitto_pub"

What would be the best solution for this? Can I increase the publish timeout for mosquitto bridge? Any other alternative solution?

Mosquitto version: 1.4.14

Mosquitto Bridge config:

```
connection MQTT_Bridge
address cloud.broker.com:8883
topic ToCloud/# out 2 "" ""
remote_clientid abcd
keepalive_interval 60
bridge_cafile /certs/ca
```

Backhaul: Satellite (200kbps not sure )

Cloud broker : eMQTT

Comment: v1.4.14 is pretty old, the latest is 1.6.x. 28KB is going to eat a lot of that 200bps (28 * 8 -> 224) is anything else sending any data over the link? Also the trace shows QOS 1 but the config should be sending QOS 2 over the bridge, which is it?

Comment: Bridge config of QOS2 is actually the max QOS. If we send with QOS1 mosquitto will relay to cloud with QOS1 itself. I tested and confirmed

Comment: This looks more and more like a mosquitto issue rather than a network badwith issue. I am able to send the same payload using mosquitto_pub instantaneously by looping it in  a script

Comment: What is the latency on the link? Ping the cloud broker